# Webform CKEditor add color

Tags: 8, webforms, composer

I would like to add the possibility to change color in CKEditor, mainly for Webforms. The instructions at https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton suggest to download manually the CKEditor colorbutton plugin and then add it to /libraries: would it instead be possibile to modify composer.libraries.json and install the plugin via Composer ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you can use Composer to download front end libraries too. You'll want to put it in your project root composer.json, so it doesn't get overwritten when core or contributed modules are updated.

Comment: Webform use a custom CKEditor but you can change it to any Text format's editor with the Color button module via the HTML Editor Settings (/admin/structure/webform/config/elements)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As Clive says in his comment above, you can certainly use Composer to manage other code besides Drupal core and contrib modules.

If you are keeping your code in version control such as `git`, this also has the advantage of keeping third-party code out of your project's version control repository. Just commit your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` and you can rebuild all your project dependencies when you deploy.